# Responsive menu doesn't work for firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, menu

I recently switched my menu to a responsive menu. I'm not the best with html so I used a free menu. It works perfectly fine, even on mobile, but it doesn't seem to work on firefox. Sadly our site gets a bit of traffic after some advertising for our horse and I just switched the whole site to the new design. Now I don't want people to look at our site and not see a menu so I don't know what to do which is why I'm asking for help here.

http://ykw-gypsyhorses.com/ is my website. Does anyone know how to fix it? 
I don't want to mess up my coding again so I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: add `position: relative;position: relative;z-index:1000` in `<div aria-hidden="false" style="transition: max-height 284ms ease 0s; position" class="nav-collapse nav-collapse-0 closed">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `position:absolute;` and `z-index:10000;` to the menu's selector. This will ensure that the menu stays on top.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where should I add these values in my html because when I placed them in the order where I thought they should be it would take away the menu in chrome as well. So I'm not doing it right. Also thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: This is CSS. Add an attribute `class="xyz"` inside your menu's opening tag. Now, after your `<head>` tag, add a `<style type="text/css">` tag. Now put `.xyz{position:absolute; z-index:10000;}` and after that, close the style tag (`</style>`)

Comment: Yeah, I probably didn't do that correctly cause it messed up my coding again. My menu is <div class="nav-collapse"> already. I need to keep that in order to make the menu work, if I add a class for xyz I don't know how to add that?

Comment: Do everything i said in the last comment, but don't put `class=xyz` and instead of `.xyz{position:absolute; z-index:10000;}` , put `.nav-collapse{position:absolute; z-index:10000;}` in style tag.

Comment: It has taken the menu up, but has not bumped down the slider. Basically the menu is showing on top of the slider images, and the logo on the left incl the green bar for the menu background are still not showing. Any other ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Try this final trick - in your css file here : [CSS](http://ykw-gypsyhorses.com/css/style.css), find `#header`. Remove `padding:0;`  there and add `padding-top:1px;`

Comment: I added the padding to the header, and it solved the problem. Thank you very much.